# how do i use strace to know about system calls in my C program

Tags: c, system-calls, strace

I'd like to know how to use strace to trace system calls in my C program and how to use it for debugging my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By running your program through strace:

```
strace path/to/your/executable
```

e.g. `strace ./myapp`

Answer (score 4):

Run `strace [arguments to strace] your_program [arguments to your program]`. See `man strace` or just `strace` without arguments for the possible arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Strace is great to see system calls. Once you understand how it works, be sure to check out [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) as well, which shows calls to dynamically linked libraries.

Together, they give you a *very* good understanding of what any given program is doing (unless statically linked, of course).